# SuppressionXpathFilter in Checkstyle 10.9.3 sun_checks10.xml file is not ignoring what's specified in my xpath-suppressions.xml file

Tags: checkstyle

I am using Java 17 and Checkstyle 10.9.3.  I have a sun_checks10.xml file that contains the following (where /path_to_xml is my absolute path to the xpath-suppressions.xml file):

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
        <property name="file" value="/path_to_xml/xpath-suppressions.xml"/>
        <property name="optional" value="false"/>
    </module>
. . .
```

I have a file /path_to_xml/xpath-suppressions.xml that contains the following, as I wish to ignore issues found in generated code over which I have no control (methods named 'initComponents'):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionXpathFilter Experimental Configuration 1.2//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2_xpath_experimental.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress-xpath checks=".*" query="//METHOD_DEF[./IDENT[@text='initComponents']]"/>
</suppressions>
```

I have stripped down a file that contains said method and I run Checkstyle on the command line like this:

java -jar checkstyle-10.9.3-all.jar -c sun_checks10.xml -o output.txt PlantView.java

I am unable to get Checkstyle to ignore the method.  I have looked at the AST (abstract syntax tree) using this command:

java -jar checkstyle-10.9.3-all.jar -T PlantView.java > PlantViewAST.txt

and the xpath query looks correct.  It also looks correct based on the documentation.  I put a typo in the xpath-suppressions.xml file to be sure it is getting read/parsed, which it is (obviously this doesn't mean it is being used).  I was finally able to get a SuppressionFilter module to work in the sun_checks10.xml file to ignore magic numbers but that really isn't enough.  AND, this should work.  I feel I'm missing something...

Any suggestions and/or insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Roman Ivanov who provided me the answer over on github Checkstyle discussions:

The problem is that LineLength is not child of Treewalker so filters of tree walker are not applicable.
https://checkstyle.org/config_sizes.html#LineLength_Parent_Module
Therefore, Xpath filters would not help, as Check operates on plain text file, without parsing java code to AST.

He suggested:
Use https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionCommentFilter

However I used the following on each method I wanted to ignore, even though there were many, many files:
@SuppressWarnings("all")

Some will not like this solution b/c ignoring warnings is counter-indicated but I have no control over that code.

Note: I also had to include the following in my sun_checks10.xml file:

Inside TreeWalker module:

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>  
<module name="SuppressWarningsHolder"/>
```

Outside TreeWalker module:

```
<module name="SuppressWarningsFilter"/>
```